# Disable Content from Another Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my First Question here. I'am developing an Web Tool at the Moment and i searching for a Answer on my Question. The Problem is the following:

I have two pages one Admin Page and one User Page. The URL's are like this 
admin.php?id=123456 and user.php?id=123456

In the User page there is a text box were you can Ask Questions. Now i want to hide this Box by Clicking on a Button on my Admin Page.

Is there Any solution how i can disable a div by Clicking a button on another Page ?

The Div looks like This:

```
<h3>Ask your Question</h3>
     <br>
     <div id="Questionarea"> 
 <form role="form" action="ask.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
     <textarea rows='3' name='question' placeholder='Insert your Question'></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-ask">Ask</button>
     </div>
 </form>
     </div>
```

I want do Disable The div Questionarea when i click a Button which is on another page is this Possible ? Thanks for answers.

Comment: when you click on a button in admin page and redirecting it to user page? you would like to disable it then?

Comment: You want set the status of this section from the other page. So you need to save this flag value somwhere...may be in database. And whenever you come back to this page, check the flag value and take the decision. Hope it is clear to you.

Comment: I suggest to store this value in a DataBase table, and when the user access his session, check if `Questionarea` is enabled or disabled..

Comment: @G_S I dont want to redirect it should be disabled on the users screen when i click the button at the admin screen...

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Thanks that is a nice solution but is there any other solution ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui but that would mean that the user need to reload the page to make the Change happen...

Comment: @schali95: instead of database, you may try storing the flag in cache.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Okay but this seems more comlicated for me i'am a newbie in Webdeveloping and doesn't really know how to implement a cache :D

Comment: @schali95: you will get many articles on internet on this implementation. its not much difficult. Check for jquery localstorage. These tags will be helpful to you while searching

Comment: @RakeshBurbure okay thanks i take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the status of the button's visibility in your database. So you can disable the button in admin page. And in the Users Page add an if statemt to see if the visibily is true or not. If the visibily is false, hide the button. Something like this code in User page:

```
<h3>Ask your Question</h3>
<br>
<?php if ($button_visible == true){ ?>
<div id="Questionarea"> 
    <form role="form" action="ask.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows='3' name='question' placeholder='Insert your Question'></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-ask">Ask</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer isn't there any other solution than a database entry ?

Comment: Actually No. There isn't any other reliable method to do it. You can use cookies but only if these two pages are in the same client and the same browser. And user can simply delete that cookie so it's not reliable at all.

Comment: If you want to do it without refreshing the page you need to use ajax in user page. so it'll check the visibility flag every 5 seconds for example and if it's false, the javascript code will remove the `Questionarea` id.

Comment: This sounds nice have you any example for me how i can implement this ?